# SELinux on Ubuntu 18

Tags: server

I’ve been hitting my head agains the wall trying to configure SELinux on Ubuntu 18, is there any official documentation
to do that or is not supported anymore ?

I only can make it work on 16 LTS with enforcing. On 16 LTS by installing `selinux` package or

```
apt-get install selinux-basics selinux-policy-default auditd
```

and then run

```
selinux-activate
```

it works, but on 18 it seems something changed and cannot make it work, I been configuring the service at boot with this

Add `security=selinux selinux=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub`. Run the following command: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Then I reboot, I get Permissive by default, then if I set to enforcing from command line everything stops working, I mean, if I reboot the server it does not boot anymore.

I cannot restart services, everything is denied which is wrong, so I would like to know if I should keep trying, as I said, on 16 LTS it works.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Selinux works for me on Ubuntu 18. All I had to do was to install selinux and selinux-basics, and then activate it. Note that in my grub config I only have `security=selinux` and not `selinux=1`